# Why do I need to declare a variable in main if it is a return value in Java?

Tags: java, variables, return-value, variable-declaration

(Sorry if this is so beginner. I'm in an intro class.) Why is Java telling me to declare and initialize 'piglatin' as a variable in the main method when it's a return value? I thought that once it gets initialized in pigLatinWord, it doesn't need to be reinitialized in main?

```
import java.util.*;

public class PigLatin {

//This program prints our the pig latin version of words.

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);       
    String word;

    System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
    word = console.next();

    pigLatinWord(word);

    System.out.println(word + " in pig latin is " + piglatin);
}

    //translates words starting with vowels, "th," consonants into piglatin
    public static String pigLatinWord (String word) {

    char c = word.charAt(0);
      String piglatin;
    if (c == 'a' ||  c == 'e' || c == 'i' || 
                 c == 'o' || c == 'u'){  //if word starts with a vowel
                 piglatin = word + "-hay";      
              } else if (word.startsWith("th")) {  //if word starts with "th"
                  piglatin = word.substring(2) + "-thay";
              } else {
                 piglatin = word.substring(1) + "-" + word.charAt(0) + "ay";
              }
      return piglatin;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably when you write

```
pigLatinWord(word);
```

You mean to assign the return value of this method to some variable. Specifically, you probably want:

```
String piglatin = pigLatinWord(word); //Creates a String variable reference to the return value of this method
```

Only then can you refer to such a variable in your `main` method.

Answer (score 1):

When you are writing `System.out.println(word + " in pig latin is " + piglatin);` , compiler will expect `piglatin` variable to be declared inside main method but its not there. Hence its throwing error.

You can write :

```
String piglatin = pigLatinWord(word);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can print your returned pigLatinWord directly like this:

```
System.out.println(word + " in pig latin is " + pigLatinWord(word));
```

Reason behind the error:
  Scope of the variable 'piglatin' is limited to pigLatinWord (String word) method. Hence you can't use this variable outside of your pigLatinWord() method.

If you want to access the value returned by your pigLatinWord() method, you can declare a new variable within main() method to store the returned value and use it to print:

```
String translatedPigLatinWord = pigLatinWord(word);
System.out.println(word + " in pig latin is " + translatedPigLatinWord);
```